# Disadvantages of using Android Compatibility Library on Honeycomb

Tags: android, compatibility, android-3.0-honeycomb

I would like to know your opinion on **disadvantages** of using ACL on Honeycomb devices.

I think of using the Library for my application **exclusively** - even when it runs on Honeycomb itself - otherwise I would have to create 2 versions of mostly identical classes.

Primarily I am interested in functionality (bugs) of Compatibility Library, its performance and memory usage vs native Honeycomb SDK. So if you have experience with creating separate classes both for ACL and for Honeycomb, let me know if results were worth the efforts - should I create duplicate classes or go with ACL-only.

As always, thanks for your support :)

Comment: As usual, I may have asked the question not as clearly as I could. What I wish to know is whether it is a good idea to create specific class (e.g. some Fragment) in two versions - one that will extend base fragment class from ACL and another that will extend base fragment class from native Honeycomb SDK. Or should I have one fragment that will only use ACL instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan to have one binary for both tablets and handsets, your fragments should all extend from the ACL -- otherwise you'll be building two apps.  The benefit of the ACL is that you can build your app once (by extending its compatibility classes) and then run those fragments on all API levels >= 4.

The biggest drawback we encountered were ACL bugs related to animations and the back button on Honeycomb -- but these were [mostly] fixed with the support package r4.  I don't recall any other issues (if there were any they were small enough that I don't remember them now).

Comment: Thanks Drew! I agree, compatibility library works on most devices, and this is way more important than some potential minor bugs or a bit (if any) slower performance.